# How many ways can you express n as the sum of three other natural numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

In particular, I was trying to find how many ways can you express 15 as the sum of three numbers (the numbers can repeat but the order doesn't matter; for example, $15 = 7+4+4$ and $15=4+4+7$ would be valid but considered equivalent). For the case n=15, I found the answer to be 19 by brute force:

$$ \begin{align} 15 &= 13+1+1 \\ &= 12 + 2 + 1 \\ &= 11 + 3 + 1 \\ &= 11 + 2 + 2 \\ &= 10 + 4 + 1 \\ &... \\ &= 6 + 5 + 4 \\ &= 5 + 5 + 5 \end{align} $$

However, how would you solve it using a more "intelligent" method? How to generalize it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts

Comment: you should be able to do this with a simple geometric picture:  integer triples in the triangle $x+y+z=n,$  with $x,y,z \geq 0.$ There are exactly three points with two coordinates $0,$   as $(n,0,0).$   You need the count with one zero, $(0,y,z)$ with $y,z>0$ and $y+z=n$ if $n$ is divisble by $3$   there is a point with $x=y=z.$   Finally, you need two equal, positive $x,z$  with $x+x+z=n.$   With all this, your count is a certain combination of those counts (with fractional coefficients).

Comment: apparently the triangle with $x,y,z$  positive  has $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$  integer points, easier than I expected. You still need to slice up the triangle, points with $x=y=z$  when possible, then two of them equal, then all three different.

Comment: @user2661923 I believe this is not a Stars and Bars problem. It's already explicitly stated that $7+4+4$ and $4+4+7$ is counted once; Stars and Bars would treat them as two different things.

Comment: @VTand Yeah, Stars and Bars would overcount. Maybe to fix it we could divide by 6 whenever $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are all different, and by 3 whenever $x_1=x_2 \ne x_3$. However, this still includes casework and manually counting (though much neater than pure brute force)

Comment: @VTand Good catch, I missed that.  I deleted my comment.

Comment: @WillJagy That is a really cool approach, though I am having a bit of hard time visualizing the triangle in three dimensions. How did you find it to have $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$ integer points?

Comment: @Luigui1729 The number of integer points there is exactly the number of positive solutions $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ for the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = n$. Using stars and bars, you can find that the number is $\binom{n-1}{2}$.